# How to use scrollview to a viewcontroller with UILabels and TableViews

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

My TableView rows varies in size. I want to scroll it down.. But I don't know how to use a scrollview.. I've added a scrollview below the other content views.. I also assigned an IBOutlet, but i don't know what to code or something.. Also it works but it bounces back to the viewable screen only, I need to hold the screen to steady the view.. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: can you explain in detail what you want to achieve?

Comment: @iOSDeveloper I just want my scrollview to work.. where do I put the contentSize?

Comment: if your content size is greater than your device screen size then you have to set content size otherwise there is not require to set content size just remain as it is

Comment: where do I put the `contentSize`

Comment: where you want like in viewDidLoad  or viewDidAppear? But I think you should set content size of scrollview after filling data in scrollview.

Comment: set your UIScrollView content size using YourscrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, HeightOfContent);

Comment: where will you give me +1? I didn't give answer. :)

Comment: @iOSDeveloper I really don't know how this work :))) I have a follow-up.. it bounces back. How do I stop it to a specific point?